# Xamarin Studio stalls at "Installing Shared Runtime"

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment

I'm building the Very First intro-level app with Xamarin Studio, the Hello.Droid app. Basically, it's an empty shell built directly from the multi-platform single-form template. The Hello.iOS project builds and deploys to an emulator perfectly. Trying the same thing with the Hello.Droid project, it Builds fine, but hangs when I try to deploy it, it stalls with "Installing Shared Runtime" at the top of the screen.

The emulator starts up, but control never seems to be transferred to it. It stays hung at "Installing Shared Runtime" for hours. What's wrong? This is as simple as it gets!

Comment: That could be an issue with the emulator.. Have you tried using a real device? just in case

Comment: Don't have an Android phone. And if it **is** an issue with the emulator, what do I do about it? How do I test this theory without a phone? I tried a different emulator, with the same results.

Comment: A couple of things to check first:

1. Boot up your Android Emulator and ensure it loads to the home screen. Make sure you can also interact with it. 2. Then try to deploy with the Shared Runtime, if it hangs/fails please go to your `Properties` of your project and uncheck `Use Shared Runtime`.

Comment: This may be a significant clue. NONE of my Android Emulators finish loading to the home screen. They all just sit with the word ANDROID on the screen. Is there something expected of me at this point, or are they all hanging? And if hanging...what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Because I'm having the exact same issue currently...

Comment: Ditto! Waiting almost half an hour for it to finish.